# How to make a dotted word placeholder?

Tags: boxes, framed

I want to make a word place holder similar to the unicode DOTTED CIRCLE (which is used to demonstrate the placement of diacritics and similar combining symbols). I want to make a box n characters long and place diacritics below the box at the ith position and above the box at the jth position (etc).  I've tried to experiment with \framebox but I cannot make it not extend below the baseline.

A rather crappy sample of what I want to achieve is this: [image]

Those squiggles are tropes, or grammatical/musical signs, they sit (mostly) outside of the bounding box of the letters. The words are irrelevant, but the structure of the phrase is relevant.

Comment: I do a wild guess that you're creating some kind of handout or examination  for students. Did you have a look at the [exam package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)?

Comment: Please provide a picture of the type of output you want.

Comment: More info and an illustration.